# how to split a string on every parenthese and keep all text into an array in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to **split** a string **on every parenthese** into an array and **keep all text** in C#, get everything in the parenthese.

Example: "*hmmmmmmmm (asdfhqwe)asasd*"

Should become: "***hmmmmmmmm***", "***(asdfhqwe)***" and "***asasd***".

My current setup is **only** able to take everything **inside** the parentheses and discards the rest.

```
var output = input.Split('(', ')').Where((item, index) => index % 2 != 0).ToList();
```

How would i go forward to do such thing (disregarding my current code) ?

Comment: Sounds like a good use for regular expressions.

Comment: Just write a lexer. Lexers are not hard to write!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regrx split with positive look-ahead and look-behind and an optional space; then filter out empty strings.

```
var tokens = Regex
    .Split(str, @"(?<=[)])\s*|\s*(?=[(])")
    .Where(s => s != string.Empty)
    .ToList();
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/2sTuIf)

Comment: This gives: hmmmmmmmm, (, asdfhqwe), asasd, rather than hmmmmmmmm, (asdfhqwe), asasd.

Comment: @7h3w1z4rd Please take a look at the edit and a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Oky so I do not know what the real string will look like in your application, but based on the provided string this will be my hack of a solution:

```
string sample = "hmmmmmmmm (asdfhqwe)asasd";
var result = sample.Replace("(", ",(").Replace(")", "),").Split(',');
```

So i replaced where the split should be with a comma, but you can use any other char that might never occur in your string, Say like the '~' could also work.

But not knowing all the required functionality, this would work for above scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
string[] subString = myString.Split(new char[] { '(', ')' });
```

Comment: That's what you were asking for in the original question :)