# How to get parentheses inside parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to keep a parenthese within a string that's surrounded by a parenthese.

The string in question is: `test (blue,(hmmm) derp)`

The desired output into an array is: `test` and `(blue,(hmmm) derp)`.

The current output is: `(blue,`, `(hmm)` and `derp)`.

My current code is thatof [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48857835/5659664):

```
var input = Regex
  .Split(line, @"(\([^()]*\))")
  .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
  .ToList();
```

How can i extract the text inside the outside parentheses (keeping them) and keep the inside parenthese as one string in an array?

**EDIT:**

To clarify my question, I want to ignore the inner parentheses and only split on the outer parentheses.

`herpdediderp (orange,(hmm)) some other crap (red,hmm)`

Should become:

`herpdediderp`, `orange,(hmm)`, `some other crap` and `red,hmm`.

The code works for everything except the double parentheses: `(orange,(hmm))` to `orange,(hmm)`.

Comment: What do you do if there are no outside parentheses?

Comment: @NetMage then it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I meant, is it possible the input string will not be surrounded by parentheses, and if that happens, how should it be handled?

Comment: @NetMage if the input string does not have any parentheses in itself, it will skip it. The string would not be surrounded by parentheses but rather i want to capture parentheses IN the string. If the string is surrounded by parentheses then it will run through that, but only go through if the first word separated from the rest by a comma is a color.

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself again. You specifically don't want to capture the parentheses in the string, or you would have `(orange, (hmm))`. Also your two examples are contradictory - how do you get both `blue`, `(hmm) derp` and `orange,(hmm)`, `red,hmmm`? But this is beginning to seem like an XY problem - what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, can parentheses be nested more than one level deep?

Comment: Yes, but it will not change the way it handles it. Even if it's `(black,(hmm(test(something))) hmmm)`. I just want to remove the outer parentheses. so it will become `black,(hmm(test(something))) hmmm`.

Comment: I firstly want to get it from `herpdediderp (orange,(hmm)) some other crap (red,hmm)` down to just `(orange,(hmm))`. The rest of checking if it is surrounded and removing outer parentheses I already have. It doesn't have to remove the parentheses at the start, I can do that later.

Comment: That completely contradicts your `(blue,(hmmm) derp)` example. Perhaps re-write the question with a clear specification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lot's o' guessing going on here - from me and the others. You could try

```
[^(]+|\([^(]*(?:\([^(]*\)[^(]*)*\)
```

It handles **one** level of parentheses recursion (could be extended though).

[Here at regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b%5e%28%5d%2b%5cb%7c%5c%28%5b%5e%28%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5b%5e%28%5d*%5c%29%5b%5e%28%5d*%29*%5c%29&i=herpdediderp+%28orange%2c%28hmm%29%29+some+other+crap+%28red%2chmm%29).

[Visual illustration at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8u97PU/2).

If this piques your interest, I'll add an explanation ;)

**Edit:**

If you need to use split, put the selection in to a group, like

```
([^(]+|\([^(]*(?:\([^(]*\)[^(]*)*\))
```

and filter out empty strings. See example [here at ideone](https://ideone.com/8wDem2).

**Edit 2:**

Not quite sure what behaviour you want with multiple levels of parentheses, but I assume this could do it for you:

```
([^(]+|\([^(]*(?:\([^(]*(?:\([^(]*\)[^(]*)*\)[^(]*)*\))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ added
```

For each level of recursion you want, you "just" add another inner level. So this is for two levels of recursion ;)

[See it here at ideone](https://ideone.com/QLGQ6U).

Comment: I've now modified the [ideone example](https://ideone.com/vbzojf) (from deleted comment) to use Split. See edit.

Comment: I don't understand where you get that it "ignores spaces". Have you checked the [ideone example](https://ideone.com/kBZSHb)? It doesn't remove/ignore any spaces.

Comment: Ahh. Between the *groups*, yes. That was intentional as I assumed that was the behavior you wanted. Well, I've changed it and now it keeps it. See edits.

Comment: Edited and added another level of recursion

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method

```
public string Trim(params char[] trimChars)
```

Like this

```
string trimmedLine = line.Trim('(', ')'); // Specify undesired leading and trailing chars.

// Specify separator characters for the split (here command and space):
string[] input = trimmedLine.Split(new[]{',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If the line can start or end with 2 consecutive parentheses, use simply good old if-statements:

```
if (line.StartsWith("(")) {
    line = line.Substring(1);
}
if (line.EndsWith(")")) {
    line = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 1);
}
string[] input = line.Split(new[]{',', ' '},
```

Comment: This will fail if the first or last item in the list has parentheses, e.g. `((green), eggs, ham)`.

Comment: The problem is that the precise syntax of his input line is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone will come up with a regex. Here's my code answer.

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public IEnumerable<string> GetStuffInsideParentheses(this IEnumerable<char> input)
    {
        int levels = 0;
        var current = new Queue<char>();
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            if (levels == 0)
            {
                if (c == '(') levels++;
                continue;
            }
            if (c == ')')
            {
                levels--; 
                if (levels == 0)
                { 
                    yield return new string(current.ToArray()); 
                    current.Clear();
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (c == '(')
            {
                levels++; 
            }
            current.Enqueue(c); 
        }
    }
}
```

Test program:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var input = new []
        {
            "(blue,(hmmm) derp)", 
            "herpdediderp (orange,(hmm)) some other crap (red,hmm)"
        };

        foreach ( var s in input )
        {
            var output = s.GetStuffInsideParentheses();
            foreach ( var o in output )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
blue,(hmmm) derp

orange,(hmm)
red,hmm
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v3upFM)

Comment: This wont work for an input such as: `herpdediderp (orange,(hmm)) some other crap (red,hmm)`.

Comment: @7h3w1z4rd What answer do you expect for that example? Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you think about the problem backwards, it becomes a bit easier - don't split on what you don't what, extract what you do want.

The only slightly tricky part if matching nested parentheses, I assume you will only go one level deep.

The first example:

```
var s1 = "(blue, (hmmm) derp)";
var input = Regex.Matches(s1, @"\((?:\(.+?\)|[^()]+)+\)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => Regex.Matches(m.Value, @"\(\w+\)|\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(m2 => m2.Value).ToArray()).ToArray();
// input is string[][] { string[] { "blue", "(hmmm)", "derp" } }
```

The second example uses an extension method:

```
public static string TrimOutside(this string src, string openDelims, string closeDelims) {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(src)) {
        var openIndex = openDelims.IndexOf(src[0]);
        if (openIndex >= 0 && src.EndsWith(closeDelims.Substring(openIndex, 1)))
            src = src.Substring(1, src.Length - 2);
    }
    return src;
}
```

The code/patterns are different because the two examples are being handled differently:

```
var s2 = "herpdediderp (orange,(hmm)) some other crap (red,hmm)";
var input3 = Regex.Matches(s2, @"\w(?:\w| )+\w|\((?:[^(]+|\([^)]+\))+\)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value.TrimOutside("(",")")).ToArray();
// input2 is string[] { "herpdediderp", "orange,(hmm)", "some other crap", "red,hmm" }
```

Comment: To clarify my question (edited soon TM), I want to ignore any parentheses that are inside the first layer of parentheses, as they don't matter in the code. I just don't want it to split on a inside parenthese when it's supposed to split on the other ones.