# How to get the whole parenthese of a string with maybe infinite level of parentheses inside

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I already saw this answer : [How to get parentheses inside parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957859/how-to-get-parentheses-inside-parentheses) but it didn't really work if I don't know the number of levels of those parentheses.

I'm actually trying to deobfuscate a js file with python, and I have this kind of string that I want to "scrape" :

```
String.fromCharCode
        (
            (010 * 12 + 6),
            (06 * (0x1 * (1 * 0xa + 6) + 1) + 12),
            (4 * 27 + 3),
            (01 * 0x3b + 50),
            (1 * 0x34 + 15),
            (1 * (1 * (3 * ((0x1 * 8 + 7) * 1 + 0) + 8) + 24) + 27),
            (0x1 * (2 * 0x25 + 7) + 16),
            (1 * 0112 + 40),
            (1 * 0x2c + 23),
            (0x3 * 042 + 9),
            (1 * ((05 * 4 + 1) * 03 + 0) + 37),
            (0x2 * (1 * 0x1f + 4) + 31)
        )
```

When I run : `re.findall(r"String.fromCharCode\((.+?)\)", content)` it returns me `String.fromCharCode((03 * (07 * 4 + 3)` at first.
So it seems like my line of code is only searching for the first occurrence of a closed parenthesis. I didn't try the answer of the above link but it seems like to not be "infinite", we should know beforehand the number of levels.

And what I want to get is the whole parenthesis like that : `((010 * 12 + 6),(06 * (0x1 * (1 * 0xa + 6) + 1) + 12),(4 * 27 + 3),(01 * 0x3b + 50),(1 * 0x34 + 15),(1 * (1 * (3 * ((0x1 * 8 + 7) * 1 + 0) + 8) + 24) + 27),(0x1 * (2 * 0x25 + 7) + 16),(1 * 0112 + 40),(1 * 0x2c + 23),(0x3 * 042 + 9),(1 * ((05 * 4 + 1) * 03 + 0) + 37),(0x2 * (1 * 0x1f + 4) + 31))`

**EDIT:**

To clarify, the code have many other occurrence of the "`String.fromCharCode`" that is above. If I were to delete the `?` in the regex code, it will retrieve the entire code.

**EDIT2:**

I've made a thing : https://pastebin.com/BVtD8R51
It seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this is really the right way to tackle the problem but you might get along with a recursive approach and the newer `regex` module:

```
String\.fromCharCode[^()]*
(
    \(
        (?:[^()]|(?1))*
    \)
)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/dcjjWJ/2).

---

Which in `Python` could be:

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r'''
    String\.fromCharCode[^()]*
    (
        \(
            (?:[^()]|(?1))*
        \)
    )
''', re.VERBOSE)

for snippet in rx.finditer(your_string_here):
    print(snippet.group(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` qualifier in python is greedy by default, so it will match as much as it can. You've added a `?` after it which makes it non-greedy. Take the `?` out and it should match all the way to the next close bracket, but it will also match further than that if it can find other close brackets further into your input, even if that's outside the `fromCharCode` close bracket.

Comment: The thing is the code I showed is recurrent in the code I want to deobfuscate, if I delete the `?`, it will take the other parentheses with to the very end.